# Problem with left_join or How to convert character (in scientific form) to character (to numeric form)?

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion, left-join, scientific-notation

I want to join two DFs by couple of variables. All of variables have to remain `as.character`.
However, one is converted to scientific notation.
Question is, how do I transform `data2$ID_Value` to character to "XX00000000" form?
Converting to numeric and joining works, but I have to play with characters.

#this works

```
data1 <- data1 %>% mutate(ID_Value = as.double(ID_Value))
data2 <- data2 %>% mutate(ID_Value = as.double(ID_Value))
data.join <- left_join(data2, data1, by = c("Coding", "ID_Value", "Year"))
```

#How to join with type(ID_Value) = as.character?

#Here is the data.

```
data1 <-
structure(list(Coding = c("PL01", "PL01", "PL02", "PL03", "PL03", 
"PL04", "PL05", "PL06", "PL07", "PL08", "PL09", "PL10", "PL10", 
"PL11", "PL13", "PL13", "PL14", "PL16", "PL17"), ID_Value = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 11L, 7L), .Label = c("1100000000", "1140000000", "2120000000", 
"2240000000", "3060000000", "3200000000", "3260000000", "4300000000", 
"4320000000", "5020000000", "6040000000", "6220000000"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
    "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
    "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010"), `1814` = c(5787.88072428485, 
    27730.4960757182, 5787.88072428485, 8932.52590304165, 1977.15424781852, 
    22593.7415704718, 18845.7534728209, 10534.5762707541, 5722.88747773182, 
    6536.13205513642, 2706.63712073692, 8932.52590304165, 29410.372540196, 
    1774.21615143866, 5787.88072428485, 29410.372540196, 27730.4960757182, 
    6536.13205513642, 1977.15424781852)), row.names = c(NA, -19L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data2 <- 
structure(list(Coding = c("PL01", "PL01", "PL02", "PL03", "PL03", 
"PL04", "PL05", "PL06", "PL07", "PL08", "PL09", "PL10", "PL10", 
"PL11", "PL13", "PL13", "PL14", "PL16", "PL17"), ID_Value = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 11L, 6L), .Label = c("1.14e+09", "1.1e+09", "2.12e+09", "2.24e+09", 
"3.06e+09", "3.26e+09", "3.2e+09", "4.32e+09", "4.3e+09", "5.02e+09", 
"6.04e+09", "6.22e+09"), class = "factor"), Year = c("2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try `data2$ID_Value <- as.numeric(as.character(data2$ID_Value))`

Comment: Whatever process you used to generate `data2` has lost information: there is no way to go back from `1.14e+09` to (perhaps) `1140000000` with certainty (since `1140000001` gives the same scientific notation in most cases). I suggest you go back some steps in your data munging to find out how `data2$ID_Value` was converted into that notation and fix it there.